# Method of characteristics for higher order PDEs in more than two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am trying to understand the mathod of characteristics for solving partial differential equations. However, all the examples I found over the internet are for first order PDEs or for second order PDEs in two variables.

I could not find a single example where the solutions of a second order PDE in three variables are found via the method of characteristics. Could anyone give me a reference where I could fine such an example?

Comment: I suggest you try posting this on MathOverflow, where Robert Bryant might see and answer it.